# Can there be two init processes?

Tags: command-line, scripts, process, init

I am new to Operating Systems (specifically Linux) and this is my first question here

I want to ask, can there be two process with CMD = init (as given by `ps - e` command).

I had two processes on my laptop with CMD = init (id's 1 (this is default) and 29179).
I wrote a c++ program and created a child and waited for parent to exit (orphaned the child) and then checked the child's ppid but it gave 29179.

Here is my C++ program : [Prog.cpp](http://ideone.com/3Gshdf) 
(on Ideone all output of stdout is not printed may be the way it is.)

Here is stdout of my C++ Program and output of `ps -e` on my laptop (Only 2 links allowed) :  [output](http://pastebin.com/4n5v1F6m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to have *multiple* `init` processes.

In the olden days before Upstart, there was just one `init` process (where `PID = 1`).

Now, with Upstart, there's the original `init` process (where `PID = 1`).

But, when a user logs in, a new `init` process is created for that user session. Thus, that is why you see the second `init` process (where `PID != 1`).

Comment: Who is the parent of then this second `init` process?

Comment: All processes (other than yours) have the parent of the original init (pid = 1). Your processes (user) have the parent of the second init (where pid != 1).